# How can I get xeyes to work? - XQuartz Display Error on Local System

Tags: x11, display, macos

I installed XQuartz on my Mac (Big Sur, v. 11.5.2) using the download available on https://www.xquartz.org/ (XQuartz-2.8.1.dmg), but I have been unable to use it. I've been failing to fix this issue for the past couple of weeks, and I'm really hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

I've been using xeyes to test the installation and get the following response:

```
(base) magnoliafork ~ % xeyes                            
Error: Can't open display: :0.0
(base) magnoliafork ~ % echo "$DISPLAY"
:0.0
```

One of the ways in which I have tried fixing it is to set my `DISPLAY` inside my `.zshrc` file to `:0`, `localhost=0`, and just the number `0`. I also tried putting my IP address in front of the `:0.0` at one point. None of those solutions worked.

```
##### DISPLAY, for plotting
PATH="/opt/:$PATH"
export DISPLAY
DISPLAY=":0.0"
```

Someone in another thread recommended changing the default options in the `sshd_config` file, so I updated the X11 options as shown below:

```
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseForwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
```

It's still not working, and I suspect the previous solution was to fix the case where you can get XQuartz to work locally but not through ssh. I can't even get it to work locally, and at this point, I have no idea what to try next. Any ideas would be really helpful!

Don't know if this is helpful, but I copied this from my console:

```
X11.app: do_start_x11_server(): argc=7
     argv[0] = /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz
     argv[1] = :0
     argv[2] = -nolisten
     argv[3] = tcp
     argv[4] = -iglx
     argv[5] = -auth
     argv[6] = /Users/magnoliafork/.serverauth.2211
```

More info for comments:

- When I run xeyes from the Apple terminal, the XQuartz icon does not pop up.
- If I try to run XQuartz directly from the Apple terminal using the `xquartz` command, the XQuartz icon pops up, and then I get a problem report from Apple that says, "Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running"
- I can run xeyes from the XQuartz terminal "xterm", but I would really prefer the Apple terminal since it is more functional.

Comment: Try typing `xhost +` before running xeyes

Comment: (1) Please update question and describe how you installed XQuartz. (On my Mac, I used homebrew, and it's running out of the box). (2) Is XQuartz actually running? (You should see the icon in the doc). (3) `:0.0` and `:0` are the same, and if `xeyes` is already using it, setting it won't help. (4) My `DISPLAY` is actually set to `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.K3RIGC7Bk3/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`, so possibly you need the full socket path (I never investigated because it works out of the box for me).

Comment: In addition to dirkt's comment, point (2), when you open Xquartz, does a terminal appear? Are you trying to run xeyes from *that* terminal (within Xquartz), or from a standard terminal application (from the Utilities folder)? If you [edit] your question and add a screenshot of you trying to run xeyes (and the resulting error(s)) from within Xquartz, that might help clarify the issue.

Comment: @Greenonline When I try that, I get this error: ```xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"```

Comment: Try the following: Open xterm, test if xeyes runs. Do `echo $DISPLAY` in this xterm, edit question with value. Open an Apple Terminal, do `export DISPLAY=...` with the value from before. Then try to run xeyes in the Apple Terminal.

Comment: @dirkt I tried that, and it is reporting the same $DISPLAY value ```:0.0```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: In an attempt to clearly differentiate between the Finder (and associated applications) and binaries run from the terminal, I am using **Bold** and `code formatting` respectively.

---

You seem to have two issues:

- Launching XQuartz installation from the terminal
- Setting the `DISPLAY` env var correctly

The first issue is that you installed **XQuartz** using a `.dmg`, rather than via `brew`, and installed it in the **Finder**. This means that you need to launch it either via the Finder or on the command line using

```
$ /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11 &
```

**Note**: My version of XQuartz was *also* installed via a `.dmg` and maybe because of this, I don't appear to have an `xquartz` command available to launch XQuartz via the **Terminal** - hence the usage of the `X11` binary from within the **XQuartz** application bundle.

---

As it now appears that you are trying to run `xeyes` from an instance of the **Terminal** application, rather than from the `xterm` running inside **XQuartz**, the solution is quite simple.

You need to get the `DISPLAY` of your **XQuartz** and assign it to the `DISPLAY` of your **Terminal** application.

First launch **XQuartz** either from the **Finder**, or using the command line that I specified above.

In the xterm in **XQuartz** type

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

This should give you something like

```
bash-3.2$ echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8cSMuyvAKe/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
bash-3.2$
```

Now in the **Terminal**, type (substituting in *your* full `DISPLAY` value)

```
$ export DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8cSMuyvAKe/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

and then

```
$ xeyes
```

and then xeyes *should* appear in the **XQuartz** session.

---

Note this works on XQuartz 2.7.11 running on High Sierra 10.13.6. You could have a Big Sur specific issue.

Comment: In xterm, I get the following, which is the same as what I get in the Apple Terminal.  ```(base) magnoliafork ~ % echo $DISPLAY :0.0 ``` I used the dmg to install on my last MacBook, and it worked like a champ. Something weird is happening with my new MacBook. My gut tells me it's something to do with the listening, but I don't know enough about XQuartz to mess with those settings.

Comment: I installed my XQuartz using the .dmg - sorry, I hadn't made that clear. One thing I can't understand is why you get `% echo $DISPLAY :0.0`. If you enter `echo $DISPLAY` you should get something other than `:0.0` returned (i.e. a preceding name of the display). Also the return value should be on the following line, so I can't understand why the `:0.0` is on the same line as the command `echo $DISPLAY`. The problem is that as I can't reproduce the issue that you have, therefore I can't really solve it, I guess.

Comment: The value was on the next line, but the comment box took out the return. Something you mentioned at the top of your answer actually worked for me (just running XQuartz from the terminal app). I tried your command, and then I was able to get xeyes and my other program to work. It doesn't solve the root problem, but I wrote an alias in my .zshrc file for it ("openXQuartz"). For now, I will type in the alias and then proceed with my work. Thank you!!

Comment: Ah good, I'm glad that you have a workaround. BTW, you should really post your final solution as an answer, for a couple of reasons: (1) To help others with the same issue find the solution/workaround more easily, than having to read through our comments (which are a bit back-and-forth as we worked towards the solution), and (2) comments are ephemeral in nature and tend to be deleted over time. One last thing, it is a bit intriguing that `xquartz` behaves differently to the `X11` binary. I can't test that, as I don't have an `xquartz` command available.